# Tomcat - JSF 2.2 - NullPointerException al iniciar el servidor

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tomcat, maven, richfaces

estoy tratando de desplegar una aplicación web (*war*) en *Tomcat 8.5*. La aplicación está hecha en *Java 8* con *Maven*, *Mojarra 2.3.2*. Adicional estoy utilizando *Primefaces 6.1*, *Richfaces 4.3.7* (esa union de *prime* y *rich* ya estaba hecha desde antes de yo llegar y al ser una aplicación sumamente grande no es facil quitar uno de ellos) y tambien uso *[Omnifaces](http://omnifaces.org) 2.3.4*.

La apliacion está con *CDI*. Instalé *Weld* en Tomcat, siguiendo esta [guía](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html).

El punto es que cada vez que inicio la aplicación, surge el siguiente error:

```
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
sep 15, 2017 3:20:16 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMACIÓN: Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no contenía TLDs. Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs. Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
sep 15, 2017 3:20:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing AtmosphereFramework
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
sep 15, 2017 3:20:21 PM org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer logOmniFacesVersion
INFORMACIÓN: Using OmniFaces version 2.6.4
sep 15, 2017 3:20:21 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMACIÓN: Inicializando Mojarra 2.3.2 ( 20170627-2139 e63598abf2ed2bb1a24674f308a734e0dce18a72) para el contexto '/sishos'
sep 15, 2017 3:20:22 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMACIÓN: JSF1048: hay presentes anotaciones PostConstruct/PreDestroy.  Los métodos de beans administrados marcados con estas anotaciones procesarán dichas anotaciones.
sep 15, 2017 3:20:23 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
GRAVE: Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.add(CompositeELResolver.java:47)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.addRootELResolver(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.addEL3_0_Resolvers(ELUtils.java:336)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:258)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:499)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.performOneTimeELInitialization(ApplicationImpl.java:1404)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:526)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.getELResolver(ApplicationWrapper.java:621)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.getELResolver(ApplicationWrapper.java:621)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

sep 15, 2017 3:20:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.add(CompositeELResolver.java:47)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.addRootELResolver(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.addEL3_0_Resolvers(ELUtils.java:336)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:258)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:499)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.performOneTimeELInitialization(ApplicationImpl.java:1404)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:526)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.getELResolver(ApplicationWrapper.java:621)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.getELResolver(ApplicationWrapper.java:621)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:256)
    ... 9 more

sep 15, 2017 3:20:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
sep 15, 2017 3:20:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Falló en arranque del Contexto [/sishos] debido a errores previos
sep 15, 2017 3:20:23 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
GRAVE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.richfaces.application.ServiceTracker.release(ServiceTracker.java:135)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.onStop(InitializationListener.java:142)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.processEvent(InitializationListener.java:154)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:147)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2291)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2264)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:348)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:761)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:761)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5429)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

sep 15, 2017 3:20:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sep 15, 2017 3:20:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
sep 15, 2017 3:20:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 14024 ms
```

Este es mi pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hdlv</groupId>
    <artifactId>sishos</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <argLine>-Xmx128m</argLine>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>sishos</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>http://192.168.1.39:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>http://192.168.1.39:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ec.com.opensonsulting</groupId>
            <artifactId>integrator</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.jms/jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-components-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-core-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.cdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.js2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.10.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.10.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.com.robust-it/cloning -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.com.robust-it</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloning</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>currentDate</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>exito</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login/main.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>salir</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login/main.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <validator>
        <validator-id>ValidatorContacto</validator-id>
        <validator-class>ec.com.hdlv.sishos.web.validator.ValidatorContacto</validator-class>
    </validator>
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>ec.com.hdlv.sishos.web.common.resources.ApplicationResources</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>ec.com.hdlv.sishos.app.recurso.sistemahospitalario</base-name>
            <var>msgapp</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>es</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <message-bundle>ec.com.hdlv.sishos.web.common.resources.messages</message-bundle>
        <el-resolver>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
    <factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FacesMessageExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>
    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>
</faces-config>
```

Coloco lo relevante del pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

No se que por donde está el error. Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Mi error fue que en el pom.xml he tenido mal el scope de algunas dependencias, a continuación muestro el cambio que hice y tomcat desplegó la aplicación sin problemas, adicional me faltaba la librería *jsf-impl*:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlrpc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva. Saludos.